# How to configure django inline formsets for many-to-many relations to be displayed in templates?

Tags: django, many-to-many, inline-formset

I have two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profileName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RelatedProfile(models.Model):
    relatedProf = models.ManyToManyField(UseCaseProfile, through='UseCaseProfileRelatedUseCase')
    relationType= models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=RELATION_CHOICE)
```

By following the Django documentation of ManyToMany relationships, I have created this table below:

```
class ProfileRelated(models.Model):
    prof = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related = models.ForeignKey(RelatedProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am aiming to have an inlineformset where the parent model is Profile and the child model is RelatedProfile. Therefore, I did the following:

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields='__all__'
class RelatedUCForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RelatedUseCase
        fields = '__all__'
RelatedUCFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile, RelatedProfile.relatedProf.through)
```

views.py (I left out unnecessary code)

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "some.html"
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['relatedProfile_form'] = RelatedUCFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object, prefix='related')
        else:
            context['relatedProfile_form'] = RelatedUCFormSet(instance=self.object, prefix='related')
        return context
```

Based on the models, forms, and view, I want to display a web page like this:

```
<pre>
Profile
     profileName: Textfield
Related
     Profile: Dropdown with related Profile
     :relationType: choicefield
</pre>
```

However, when I display my webpage, I don't get the dropdown to select which Profile I want to relate to the parent Profile. Overall, my issue is about getting the dropdown under the Related to show a list of Profiles that I could select from.